# Jquery datatables don't work on the second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I was using the jquery datatables plugin and it does not work after first page, the event click function only work on first page.

So I have found out
https://datatables.net/faqs/

**Q. My events don't work on the second page**

> A. When attaching events to cells in a table controlled by DataTables,
>   you need to be careful how it is done. Because DataTables removes
>   nodes from the DOM, events applied with a static event listener might
>   not be able to bind themselves to all nodes in the table. To overcome
>   this, simply use jQuery delegated event listener options, as shown in
>   this example. Additionally, you could use my Visual Event bookmarklet
>   to help debug event issues.

And they suggest like this:

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var name = $('td', this).eq(0).text();
    alert( 'You clicked on '+name+'\'s row' );
});
```

it works, however, In my case I need selector like this:

```
  $('#dataTables tbody tr').on('click', 'td', function (event) {
        if ($(this).attr('id') != "first" && $(this).parent().attr('data-href') !== undefined) {
            document.location = $(this).parent().attr('data-href');
        }
    });
```

How to fix the problem with keeping the selector target? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You still need to bind it to the tbody with **"#example tbody"**, then in your second selector put **"tr td"**, then it should still bind to the td after changing pages.

It's the table rows and their children that change, so binding it statically to them is still missing the point, you have to use the optional binding parameter to dive in to the changing elements, giving you access to them even after they change

Comment: No problem, if it worked you should check my answer as the answer to the question